simple commutator math problem
I am trying to grasp the concept of commutators:
I have an annihilation operator $$a = \dfrac {q + ip}{\sqrt{2}}$$
and a creation operator $$a^\star = \dfrac {q - ip}{\sqrt{2}}$$
The commutator $$[a,a^\star] = \dfrac {1}{2} [q+ip, q-ip]$$ And this is supposed to equal $$[a,a^\star] = \dfrac {1}{2}[q+ip, q-ip] = -i[q,p]=1$$
Please help me understand how $-i[q,p]$ is being derived and why is this equal to 1? (i feel so bad to be stuck at this simple problem, so thanks for helping me)

@bjcolby15 Your edit was incorrect - see update.

That's fine.  I tried to interpret it, but the correct edit seems to make better sense.

I'm going to assume that $a=\frac1{\sqrt2}(q+ip)$ and $a^*=\frac1{\sqrt2}(q-ip)$, which is consistent with the rest of your answer (I see that this isn't as in your question as there was an erroneous edit).
Then we use that $[q,q]=q^2-q^2=0$ and $[p,p]=0$ and $[q,p]=qp-pq=-(pq-qp)=-[p,q]$ and $[a+b,c+d]=(a+b)(c+d)-(c+d)(a+b)=[a,c]+[b,c]+[a,d]+[b,d]$ (just like expanding brackets for a quadratic, but being careful to maintain order) to get
$$
[a,a^*]=\frac12[q+ip,q-ip] = \frac12(i[p,q]-i[q,p])=-i[q,p] = -i^2 = 1
$$
Using that $[q,p]=i$, which is usually established early in the course.

One can also verify this by writing out the commutator explicitly, i.e., by verifying $(q+ip)(q-ip)-(q-ip)(q+ip)=-2i(qp-pq)$. But getting comfortable with bracket manipulations is an important skill in QM.

Yesss. Thank you very much for the help. Your answers were very helpful.
